# How to resolve "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [numbering];"?

Tags: java, hibernate

How to resolve "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [numbering];"?

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:could not
>   execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [numbering]; nested exception
>   is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:643)
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:106)
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy132.saveListForm(null:-1)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333)
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:308)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.saveListForm(null:-1)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.saveListForm(null:-1)
>   com.qmplus.service.impl.ServiceListFormVersionImpl.save(ServiceListFormVersionImpl.java:93)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>   org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.save(null:-1)
>   com.qmplus.web.controller.ListFormController.save(ListFormController.java:158)
>   com.qmplus.web.controller.ListFormController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$febe95eb.invoke(:-1)
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:627)
>   com.qmplus.web.controller.ListFormController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5bb46747.save(:-1)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:164)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   com.qmplus.web.interceptors.TenantFilter.doFilter(TenantFilter.java:60)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   com.qmplus.web.util.AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter.doFilter(AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter.java:47)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:71)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:202)
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:180)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Comment: I have know that i was forgetting **@Repository** in the repo

Answer (score 41):

In my case, this happens when I try to save an object in hibernate or other orm-mapping with null property which can not be null in database table.
This happens when you try to save an object, but the save action doesn't comply with the contraints of the table.

Answer (score 13):

Hibernate tries to insert data that violate underlying database integrity contraints.

There's probably misconfiguration in hibernate persistent classes and/or mapping configuration (*.hbm.xml or annotations in persitent classes).

Maybe a property of the bean you want to save is not type-compatible with its related field in database (could explain the `constraint [numbering]` part).

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was fetching data from database, changing some column values and updating it in database but for updating I was using the same save query which was violating primary key constraints i.e duplicate values for primary key, so I had written a separate query for updating the columns and it solved my problem..!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had a OneToOne relation which I was using with `@Column` by mistake. I changed it to `@JoinColumn` and added `@OneToOne` annotation and it fixed the exception.

Answer (score 3):

The solution at my end was to explicitly add a JoinColumn annotation like this:

```
@JoinColumn(name="mapping_type_id")
```

The column name is usually the table name + "_id" if there is an id field. Additionally, keep in mind which field it should be based on the relationship, OneToMany or ManyToOne.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Overall:You persist entity that is violating database rules like as saving entity that has varchar field over 250 chars ,something like that.

In my case it was a squishy problem with TestEntityManager ,because it use HSQL database /in memory database/ and it persist the user but when you try to find it ,it drops the same exception :/

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= Application.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class UserServicesTests {

@Autowired
private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Test
public void oops() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername("Toshko");
    //EMAIL IS REQUIRED:
    //user.setEmail("OPS");
    this.testEntityManager.persist(user);

    //HERE COMES TE EXCEPTION BECAUSE THE EMAIL FIELD IN TE DATABASE IS REQUIRED :
    this.userRepository.findUserByUsername("Toshko");

    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Future readers.

I have had the best luck figuring out these issues....using this method:

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyDaoObject.class);

@Transactional
public void save(MyObject item) {


    try {
         /* this is whatever code you have already...this is just an example */
        entityManager.persist(item);
        entityManager.flush();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        /* below works in conjunction with concrete logging framework */
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Now, slf4j is just a fascade (interfaces, adapter)..... you need a concrete.

When picking log4j2, you want to persist the

**`%throwable`**

So you are not flying blind, you can see %throwable at the below URL (on how you defined %throwable so it shows up in the logging.  If you're not using log4j2 as the concrete, you'll have to figure out your logging framework's version of %throwable)

https://www.baeldung.com/log4j2-appenders-layouts-filters

That %throwable, when logged, will have the **actual** SQL exception in it.

if throwable is giving you a fuss, you can do this (the below is NOT great since it does recursive log calls)

```
@Transactional
public void save(MyObject item) {


    try {
         /* this is whatever code you have already...this is just an example */
        entityManager.persist(item);
        entityManager.flush();
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        //throw ex;
        Throwable thr = ex;
        /* recursive logging warning !!! could perform very poorly, not for production....alternate idea is to use Stringbuilder and log the stringbuilder result */
        while (null != thr) {
            logger.error(thr.getMessage(), thr);
            thr = thr.getCause();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same error but I have resolved the issue in the following ways:

1. Provide all the mandatory filed of your bean/model class
2. Don't violet the concept of the unique constraint, Provide unique value in Unique constraints.

Answer (score 1):

If You try to insert other than the number in the Table column you get Constraint[numbering] error.

**Try to insert the only number (or) make your Table column to char Type**

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem while using Java Spring Boot and Hibernate. An entity field was named *rank*, which is a reserved keyword. After changing the field name to *userRank*, the issue got solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was originated after adding an UUID column to a given table.

This code DID NOT work:

```
        @Column
        private UUID uuid;
```

However this one indeed work:

```
        @Column
        @Type(type="uuid-char")
        private UUID uuid;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was DTO class is not encapsulated

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did the operation of deleting the entity before the operation of deleting (changing) records in the database containing the already deleted entity. Just swapping operations around helped.