# Create a Set of ClassA in ClassA Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, jpa

Hello I have my class ClassA and I wanna implement a Set or a list of Objects of this class in itself in SpringBoot.

I tryed it like it follows:
In my class User I have a Set and its' name is developers, I want to be able to add, delete, modify that Set when I need it.
`

```
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import fr.tse.startuppoc.project.repository.UserTypeRepository;
import fr.tse.startuppoc.project.utils.Constants;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String firstname;
    
    private String lastname;
    
    private String login;
    
    private String password;
    
    @ManyToOne // Each User have one Type but one Type can have many User
    private UserType type;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private Set<User> developers;
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    public UserType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(UserType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Set<User> getDevelopers() {
        return developers;
    }

    public void setDevelopers(Set<User> developers) {
        this.developers = developers;
    }

    public User() {     
        this.developers= new HashSet<User>();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    public User(Long id, String firstname, String lastname, String login, String password) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        
        
    }
    

}
```

Here is my test :

```html
@Test
    public void testAddDeveloper() {
        User user=new User();
        user.setType(_userTypeService.findById(Constants.ID_USER_TYPE_DEV));
        user=_userService.addUser(user);
        
        User manager=new User();
        manager.setType(_userTypeService.findById(Constants.ID_USER_TYPE_MANAGER));
        manager=_userService.addUser(manager);
        
        User falseManager=new User();
        falseManager.setType(_userTypeService.findById(Constants.ID_USER_TYPE_DEV));
        falseManager=_userService.addUser(falseManager);
        
        User admin=new User();
        admin.setType(_userTypeService.findById(Constants.ID_USER_TYPE_ADMIN));
        admin=_userService.addUser(admin);
        
        try {
            _userService.addDeveloper(manager, user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        try {
            _userService.addDeveloper(falseManager, user);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        try {
            _userService.addDeveloper(admin, user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        assertEquals(_userService.findById(manager.getId()).getDevelopers().size(), 1);
        assertEquals(_userService.findById(admin.getId()).getDevelopers().size(), 1);
        assertEquals(_userService.findById(falseManager.getId()).getDevelopers().size(), 0);
        
        
        _userService.deleteUser(admin);
        _userService.deleteUser(falseManager);
        _userService.deleteUser(manager);
        _userService.deleteUser(user);
    }
```

My problem is that when I try to delete in my JUnit tests then I get this error :

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:276)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy139.delete(Unknown Source)
    at fr.tse.startuppoc.project.service.implement.UserServiceImplement.deleteUser(UserServiceImplement.java:54)
    at fr.tse.startuppoc.project.service.implement.UserServiceImplement$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4aa0e50f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.invokeMethod(CglibAopProxy.java:386)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.access$000(CglibAopProxy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:704)
    at fr.tse.startuppoc.project.service.implement.UserServiceImplement$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$20fdef48.deleteUser(<generated>)
    at fr.tse.startuppoc.project.service.TestUserService.testAddDeveloper(TestUserService.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3698)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3958)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3303)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2438)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test_startup_poc_db`.`user_developers`, CONSTRAINT `FK7kqw0nlcsn1k6hd6lbwe33qy9` FOREIGN KEY (`developers_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 75 more
```

I don't really know how to get arround that problem if you could lend me a hand on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help I resolved my problem by following your advices and this is how I did it:

```html
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        this._userRepository.findAll().forEach(userTemp ->{
            this._userRepository.save(userTemp);
            userTemp.getDevelopers().forEach(underUser ->{
                if(underUser.getId()==user.getId()) {
                    userTemp.getDevelopers().remove(user);
                }
            });
        });
        this._userRepository.delete(this._userRepository.findById(user.getId()).orElse(null));
        
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to parent child relationship. The data is present in child table - user_developers and you are trying to delete data from parent table - user and that is not possible.

So to fix this issue first delete data from child table - user_developers and then delete data from parent table - user

Comment: Thanks I followed your advice and posted what  I did as an answer and it works !!

Comment: If you think my answer is helpful please like it to support

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason you cant delete a user is because you need to delete the relationships first before you can delete the users object.

```js
@ManyToOne // Each User have one Type but one Type can have many User
private UserType type;
    
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE })
private Set<User> developers;
```

These posts may provide further information on how to delete many to many/ many to one relationships

[How to remove entity with ManyToMany relationship in JPA (and corresponding join table rows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082095/how-to-remove-entity-with-manytomany-relationship-in-jpa-and-corresponding-join)

[How to resolve "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [numbering];"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727573/how-to-resolve-could-not-execute-statement-sql-n-a-constraint-numbering)

Comment: Thank you for your help I understand better how JPA works now !